# mysql insert stored procedure throwing an error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I am trying to write a stored procedure in mysql using Heidisql. I keep getting the error. Below is the screen shot:

[image]

below is the script of the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE index_insertPersonadata
(

  IN p_firstName   VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_middleName  VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_lastName    VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_address     VARCHAR(200),
  IN p_City        VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_State       VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_ZIP         VARCHAR(50)
)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO personalrecord(

FirstName,
MiddleName,
LastName,
Address,
City,
state,
ZIP
)
VALUES
(
    p_firstName,
    p_middleName,
    p_lastName,
    p_address,
    p_City,
    p_State,
    p_ZIP
);
END;
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your question is concerned, you are just missing a `delimiter` command:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE index_insertPersonadata (
  IN p_firstName   VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_middleName  VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_lastName    VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_address     VARCHAR(200),
  IN p_City        VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_State       VARCHAR(50),
  IN p_ZIP         VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO personalrecord(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, City, state, ZIP)
    VALUES(p_firstName, p_middleName, p_lastName, p_address, p_City, p_State, p_ZIP);
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Why you need this is [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the `delimiter` command.